# TFS Release Magament multiple deployments of same application

Tags: deployment, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I currently have a VS2015 solution that comprises of 6 applications, Web site, DB, Web Service, Console Apps.

This solution is deployed multiple times to different servers internally. At the moment i have only 5 working instances. Potentially i could end up with 10 - 20 50 etc.

I'm struggling to understand how Release Management could help me deploy this solution n number of times. Is there something else that i could perhaps use to orchestrate the deployment?

Comment: Are you using Release Management Server or the Release service that was introduced in TFS 2015 Update 2?

Comment: I'm using Release Management Server not yet progressed to TFS2015 still on TFS2013. I'm possibly looking to upgrade though did you have something in mind?

Comment: Do the upgrade the new RM introduced in TFS 2015 update 2 is such an improvement.

Comment: Once you upgrade to TFS 2015.2, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/overview

Answer (score 0):

A release definition is a collection of environments. An environment is a logical entity that represents where you want to deploy a release. You can add environment in build definition to achieve multiple deployments.

More information, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/overview